# Google Wallet for digital goods - building the tutorial

Tags: android-pay

So I'm working on getting Wallet for Digital Goods going and running into a few problems getting a Java sample up and running.

Problem #1 - I was trying to build jsontoken package and it references other packages and therefore the problem. Fortunately someone posted a jar file and am now using that.

Problem #2 - Am using the sample java snippet at link below to get the getJWT() function to work:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#2

Using the above mentioned jsontoken lib.

I'm getting undefined for

1. JsonObject
2. The type org.joda.time.Instant cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    main.java   /jsontoken/src  line 1  Java Problem
3. I can also see some other problems ISSUER, SIGNING_KEY, Issuer class etc.

---

After some searching, I added:

gson-2.2.4.jar and guava-gtw-14.0.1.jar files.

and am now down to undefines for

org.joda.time.Instant
ISSUER
SIGNING_KEY

---

Before I invest too much time, I just wanted to make sure I was headed in
the right path.

I'm planning to sell digital-goods over the web (not in-app) and was planning
to use WALLET FOR DIGITAL GOODS api - correct???

Looking at the state of these sample tutorials - is it a little bit too early
to look at it or hold off a few months.

Comment: _"digital-goods over the web (not in-app)..Digital Goods API"_ Yes. Correct. I can't help with hour JAVA questions, but if you want to see how it works on the web - [here's a sample (.Net)](http://code.edchavez.com/simple_demo) just so you see the flow.

Answer (score 0):

The "Resources -> Samples" section of the documentation contains a fully working sandbox Java sample including the source code. Give it a try at:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/samples#iap-java